# bcp utility outputs an empty file

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2005, bcp

I will use the bcp utility to debug a stored procedure, so I'd like export some data to a file.

I ran a test into my SQL-Server 2005

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @SQL = 'BCP "SELECT 1" QUERYOUT "D:\test.txt" -C -T'
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @SQL
```

I observed that the file "D:\test.txt" is created, but is empty.
What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the equivalent command:

```
BCP "SELECT 1" QUERYOUT "c:\junk\test.txt" -C -T
```

The output appeared to be an empty file, until I looked at it with a hex editor.  In the hex editor I saw this: `01 00 00 00`

So it's saving the numeric value 1 in integer format.  I suspect that you want line 2 to read:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'BCP "SELECT '1'" QUERYOUT "D:\test.txt" -C -T'
```

In which case you'll see the 1 in notepad.  In the hex editor you'd get: `01 00 31`

Because '1' is a character string length 1 with the hexadecimal value 31, the ASCII code for the character 1.

**Edit:**

You could also use the **`-w`** option to tell bcp to use unicode characters for all output.  Probably a better option since you say you'll be debugging.